# Package com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4 does not exist in Mysql Connector/J 8

Tags: java, mysql-connector

After upgrading the maven dependency for `mysql-connector-java` version 5.1.x to 8.0.x the following errors are received upon compilation:

```
[ERROR] /home/dev/testproject/src/main/java/DatabaseOperation.java:20: error: package com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4 does not exist
[ERROR] import com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException;

[ERROR] /home/dev/testproject/src/main/java/DatabaseService.java:15: error: package com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4 does not exist
[ERROR] import com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException;
```

Apparently the com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4 was removed without any deprecation or a note in the migration docs. What is the alternative now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, there was no mention of that in the release notes or migration docs. I found the relevant topic at MySQL Forums: [Connector/J 8, catching primary key violations](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,667282,667282#msg-667282). Here is an answer from MySQL representative there:

> You can catch java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.
>   MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException was needed because of c/J
>   5.1 hybrid code, it does nothing specific just extends this java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.

In other words, the package has been removed to reuse the existing `java.sql` exception classes, which is a good thing, but still should've been documented. As a result of the forementioned discussion, the bug report has been created: [Bug #91439  upgrade guide needs to inform of removed/refactored exceptions](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91439)

As I further inspected the errors in my project, I found these 3 exceptions and their `java.sql` mappings:

- `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException` ->
  `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException`
- `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`
  -> `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`
- `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException`
  -> `java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException`

(and I guess any other MySQL-specific exception from jdbc4 package also maps to the analogous SQL-exception from java.sql package)

Comment: These are not 'mappings'. They are base classes, and should have been used in the first place, as being part of the JDBC API, and not vendor-specific.